# How to import Thrift into Java program?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import, thrift

I’m writing a Java-programm for school that also uses Thrift.
The problem is not so much the general programm/programm-logic itself, but just importing Thrift (to use it in a specific part).

My basic -possibly wrong- understanding is that you write the programm-code (here empfaenger.java), then you import Thrift into this file by adding the needed import-statements, e.g.:

```
import org.apache.thrift.TException;  
import org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol;  
import org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocol;  
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket ;  
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport;
```

and adding a file in the same directory from which they can actually can be imported, in this case `libthrift-0.13.0.jar`.(1) Then you later also import a compiled .thrift-file with the language-specific realization oft he IDL-code, that iself again imports some Thrift-classes. This file is here named `syncautohersteller`.

**EDIT**: The approach with the .jar-file was recommended by the prof.
Current project-structure (as seen in InteliJ):
[image]
The problem is now just that all the Thrift import-statements all throw errors, e.g.

- `empfaenger.java`

> java: package org.apache.thrift does not exist

- `syncautohersteller`

> package javax.annotation does not exist

so clearly i’m doing something wrong. 
Does anybody know how to fix this?

---

(1) I got the file from the Thrift folder (`Home/Downloads/thrift-0.13.0/lib/java/build/libs` and then the first of the three .jar-files in the folder) after installing Thrift using .`/configure`, `sudo make` and `sudo make install` and trying to verify by running “~/Downloads/thrift-0.13.0$ thrift –version” with result

> Thrift version 0.13.0

Comment: Does your program compile and run? Is it just that IntelliJ can't figure out where the imports are or do you have a general problem that you can't build your project?

Comment: The jars must be added to the module dependencies, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IntellJ Idea to add external Jars you can find some useful information in this question: [Correct way to add external jars (lib/*.jar) to an IntelliJ IDEA project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1051640/2993413).

---

I suggest you to manage the project's dependencies through [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html), which help you to add JAR dependencies to the classpath in a simpler way.
First, you have to convert your project into a Maven project as explained [in IntelliJ Idea documentation.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/convert-a-regular-project-into-a-maven-project.html) 
Then you can follow these steps:

1. Go to [Maven repository website](https://mvnrepository.com/)
2. Search for `Thrift`
3. Select first result
4. Select the version you need
   [image]
5. Copy the maven dependency

   org.apache.thrift
       libthrift
       0.13.0
6. Add maven dependency to your pom.xml file
7. Execute a mvn `clean install`, after clicking the following button in IntelliJ
   [image]

   This process will help you and people which work with you to manage in a simpler way the dependencies of the project.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the simplest way with the Gradle, something like this:

`build.gradle.kts`:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.apache.thrift:libthrift:0.13.0")
}
```